# Access website API from daemon using Azure AD

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

We created a ASP.net Core website and added a API to it that we need to access from a daemon. The website is secured with Azure AD and the daemon authenticates with Azure. In the daemon, I'm using the same app credentials the site is using to get a token but when I try to access the website API with the token, I get redirected to the Microsoft login page. I'm not sure what I'm missing. I am getting a access token.

I also tried following the directions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-daemon-app-configuration?tabs=dotnet before going with the HttpClient code below.

```
using (var _client = new HttpClient())
{
    var Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", ClientID),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", ClientSecret)
    });

    var Response = await 
    _client.PostAsync($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenantUUID]/oauth2/token", Content);
    if (Response.IsSuccessStatusCode) 
    { 
        var Token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data.Token>(await Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

        Console.WriteLine("AccessToken: " + Token.access_token);

        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", Token.access_token);

        Response = await _client.GetAsync("https://localhost:44318/api/notify");
        Console.Write(await Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you get token successfully?

Comment: Yes. I'm able to display it on console.

Comment: Have you referred to https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/tree/master/1.%20Desktop%20app%20calls%20Web%20API

Comment: @JimXu I think I have but will take another look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more searching I found that I had two problems: the website wasn't set to accept Azure AD tokens and something is causing my HttpClient code not to request the right information.

To set the site to accept Azure AD tokens, I changed my startup.cs file so the `services.AddAuthentication` section now reads:

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options))
    .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
```

This only allows one default authentication method to work so either the user sign-in works or the the bearer works depending on what the `AzureADDefaults` is set to. You can  specify which one to use, which I did on my API, by decorating the class with:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)]
```

This is broken in ASP.net 2.2 but should work in 3.0 (from what I read). To work around it, change it to:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "AzureADBearer")]
```

If you want to allow the bearer token and normal logins, add `AzureAD` to the string:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "AzureADBearer, AzureAD")]
```

As for the HttpClient issue, I'm not sure what is wrong but I also switched back to Microsoft's code and used `ConfidentialClientApplication` to build the request and get the token and it's working now, along with the `startup.cs` changes.